# How does this touch switch circuit work?

Tags: transistors, diodes, bjt

This circuit is a touch switch circuit. They explained that:

> "The functionality of this circuit base mainly on the flip-flop action of TR3 and TR4. There are two options of the application i.e. Purely touch switch (on-off) and semi-action."

Here is an explanation of the touch switch:

> "The explanation will begin with: Purely touch switch (on-off): (J is left opened). When the circuit is first activated (by supplying the voltage) the LED remain dark. By touching the T terminal TR1 and TR2 start to conduct the current which makes TR3 inactive while TR4 on the contrary begins to let the current pass through. The LED finally begins to glow. On the contrary, if the T terminal is touched again the flip-flop action of TR1 and TR2 makes TR3 active while putting TR4 in standby. The LED then gives no light."

I have questions.

In this circuit, they explained that Tr3 and Tr4 are connected as a flip-flop, but I don't understand how transistors that are connected like that act like a flip-flop and what the purpose of D1 and D2 is.

Is there a way to analyze this circuit?

[image]

Comment: Component Values would help.

Comment: If you touch the T terminal TR1 will conduct and TR2 will conduct. So C4's + end will be grounded. If this makes TR3 off then what does the route of **+12V -> Relay's coil resistance -> R8 -> TR3's base** tell?

Comment: TR3's base voltage is 0 V right? And R8's current flows through R4 , R7 and TR4's base therefore TR4 turns on right?

Comment: This circuit diagram is incorrect it will not work.